# Publish Blazor wsam Host with Individual Accont

Tags: blazor, publish, webdeploy, hosted-blazor-webassembly

I have a problem with Blazor WSAM Host with Individual Account. When create new wsam project in VS2022 and update-database everything works well. register new user and login works.
But when publish in IIS, webapp not work and show HTTP 500 error page.
What should I change Before Publish it?

Blazor WSAM host with individual not work after publishing in iis.

Comment: Do you mean with VB2022, VS2022 visual studio 2022? Or really visual basic?

Comment: sorry . I mean VS2022 :)

Answer (score 0):

You should install [URL rewrite2 module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and The [.NET Core Hosting Bundle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0) on the IIS server.

Comment: I install URL Rewrite and net hosting Bundle . But this error appeare: This page isn’t working right now192.168.3.218 can't currently handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: This link can help you. https://www.dntips.ir/post/3326/blazor-5x-%d9%82%d8%b3%d9%85%d8%aa-34-%d8%aa%d9%88%d8%b2%db%8c%d8%b9-%d8%a8%d8%b1%d9%86%d8%a7%d9%85%d9%87%e2%80%8c%d9%87%d8%a7%db%8c-blazor-%d8%a8%d8%b1-%d8%b1%d9%88%db%8c-iis

Comment: Dear @amirameri, it's another exception, please ask it in separate question.

Comment: Dear AlirezaK, Please Just Create a Blazor WSAM with host and Individual user. then publish it to IIS. All this error Related to this question.